# Multiple rotate of a text element with Raphaël

Tags: rotation, raphael

I've drawn a circle and arranged some text elements radial outside of this circle with Raphael. Each of them are rotated to the center point of the circle. So far so good.

But now I want to rotate them a second time, for example 30deg. But if I do so, then all elements will rotated to 30deg.

A solution could be, that I loop through each text element, calculate "current deg + 30deg" and start the animation…

But it would be better if I could to this in a set() of elements. Unfortunately I will get the problem that every text element is rotated to 30deg…

Does anyone have an suggestion how I could do this job best?

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a simple method to accomplish this with a set.  Instead of setting a rotation value, you can append a incremental rotation to the transform like this:

```
//  assumes you have a variable named 'mySet'

mySet.animate( { transform: '...r30' }, 500, '<>' );
```

I believe this should do exactly what you intend.  If not, feel free to hurl vegetables at me.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is exactly what I'm looking for. But this "..." isn't really explained in the documentation of Raphael.

Comment: No, a lot of the subtleties of transformation are hinted at rather than spelled out.  Check out the documentation for transform (http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.transform) -- note that you can prepend changes as well!